# C# Android Xamarin - OnSurfaceTextureUpdated no more called after screen turning off despite "KeepScreenOn" flag

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, screen, surfaceview

I am making an app which read the camera stream on an Android device, computes each picture to get some info, and sends the info to another device thanks to Bluetooth.
I use an activity with an ISurfaceTextureListener to read the camera stream, and send info in the OnSurfaceTextureUpdated method.
I want this to work even if the screen is turned off by the proximity sensor of the device. I used:

```
this.Window.SetFlags(WindowManagerFlags.KeepScreenOn, WindowManagerFlags.KeepScreenOn);
```

in the OnCreate method, but it seems not to prevent the screen not to be turned off when the proximity sensor detects an object (in my case, because of the protection shell of my smartphone). As a consequence, the OnSurfaceTextureUpdated is not called and the app no more sends the info to the Bluetooth device.

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's you mean  "not to prevent the screen not to be turned off when the proximity sensor detects an object ( protection shell of my smartphone)" ?

Comment: Even if you set a "KeepScreenOn" flag, the screen still turning off ?

Comment: Sorry for my bad english ^^. I added some weeks ago the "KeepScreenOn" flag because the screen was turning off after some seconds of inactivity... By adding it, the screen no more turns off because of inactivity, but turns off when I close the protection shell (I don't know which word to use, so here is an image: [link](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71facj%2BqLOL._SY550_.jpg) ). How to prevent that ?

Comment: sorry, I dont have a phone like that, so I cant reproduce your problem.